# Create array of TimerCallback

Tags: c#

How I can create an array of one class, like TimerCallback?

I need to start a program, when this program is declared in one list, and, the program is checked is open or no, in X time and I using the TimerCallback to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var callbacks = new TimerCallback[]
            {    
              new TimerCallback(Foo),
              new TimerCallback(Bar),
              new TimerCallback(FooBar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `myTimerCallback[1] =` and `myTimerCallback[2] =`, not just three `myTimerCallback[0] =`.  The copy/paste code demon strikes again!

Comment: yes I do, Wolfgang Ziegler has updated the answer anyway to use array initialization syntax so thankyou to Wolfgang!

Answer (score 0):

As far as creating array is concerns, it's very simple:

```
int[] intArray = new int[5]; // 5 is the size of array
```